# Volley parsing giving error

Tags: android, json, networking

I am having problem with parsing Json through volley here is my logcat

```
08-13 06:05:55.523: D/Volley(902): [134] BasicNetwork.logSlowRequests: HTTP response for request=<[ ] http://www.petbasket.in/service/getProduct.php?category_id=Dog%20Soft%20Toys 0xe4f6ef05 NORMAL 1> [lifetime=12938], [size=158], [rc=200], [retryCount=0]
08-13 06:05:55.563: W/System.err(902): com.android.volley.ParseError: org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
08-13 06:05:55.563: W/System.err(902):  at com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest.parseNetworkResponse(JsonObjectRequest.java:73)
08-13 06:05:55.563: W/System.err(902):  at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:116)
08-13 06:05:55.573: W/System.err(902): Caused by: org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
08-13 06:05:55.573: W/System.err(902):  at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
08-13 06:05:55.573: W/System.err(902):  at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:158)
08-13 06:05:55.573: W/System.err(902):  at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:171)
08-13 06:05:55.573: W/System.err(902):  at com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest.parseNetworkResponse(JsonObjectRequest.java:68)
```

code I am using for parsing is

I am using this code for parsing NAYOSO

```
RequestQueue reqQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    Log.d(TAG, "just after line one in volley");

    Log.d(TAG, url.toString());
    JsonObjectRequest jr = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,
            url.toString(), null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    parseJSONResponse(response);
                    Log.d(TAG, "chal hat be" + response);
                    listViewAdapterAfterSelection.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    progress.dismiss();
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Network Problem",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    error.getCause();
                    error.printStackTrace();
                    progress.dismiss();
                }
            });
    jr.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(20000,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
    reqQueue.add(jr);

    progress = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Please Wait...",
            "Loading Products from Server...");
    /* ================================================================ */
}


private void parseJSONResponse(JSONObject response) {

    try {
        Log.v(TAG, "Before array");
        JSONArray entries = response.getJSONArray("products");

        for (int count = 0; count < entries.length(); count++) {
            JSONObject anEntry = entries.getJSONObject(count);
            Product product = new Product(anEntry.optInt("entity_id"),
                    anEntry.optString("name"),
                    anEntry.optString("short_description"),
                    anEntry.optInt("price"), anEntry.optString("thumbnail"));
            afterSelectionItems.add(product);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}`
```

Response is :

```
08-13 08:13:50.213: D/Volley(1723): [156] BasicNetwork.logSlowRequests: HTTP response for request=<[ ] http://www.petbasket.in/service/getProduct.php?category_id=Utility 0xe4f6ef05 NORMAL 1> [lifetime=9563], [size=159], [rc=200], [retryCount=0]
```

Comment: Wow, that's one seriously large json reply, and very slow. It would speed things a lot up if the thumbnails aren't dumped into the response. That being said: the actual error generated is in your stack trace: `org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject`. It looks like there may be some html present somewhere where it shouldn't be?

Comment: can you show us the code you use to parse?

Comment: I have added parsing code with question

Comment: can you please try print the JSONObject response in the logcat? and show us the result?thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For optimising the code, network call we are using Volley, in the same you should use GSON or JACKSON json parser for optimizing the json parsing speed, less coding.

JSON response formate for your request(while testing json Payload is 154kb !!):

```
{
"products": [
    {
        "short_description": "Aqua Action Ball for Dogs Karlie is for dogs", 
        "entity_id": "560", 
        "price": "400.0000", 
        "name": "Aqua Action Ball for Dogs Karlie", 
        "thumbnail": "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"
    }, 
    {
        "short_description": null, 
        "entity_id": "561", 
        "price": "400.0000", 
        "name": "Crazy Critters Skinneeez", 
        "thumbnail": "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"
    }, 
    {
        "short_description": null, 
        "entity_id": "562", 
        "price": "199.0000", 
        "name": "Dog Toy Ball With Terry Cloth Assorted Karlie", 
        "thumbnail": "/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAZABkAAD/4gxYSUNDX1BST0ZJTEUAAQEAAAxITGlubwIQAABtbnRyUkdCIFhZWiAHzgACAAkABgAxAABhY3NwTVNGVAAAAABJRUMgc1JHQgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAQAA9tYAAQAAAADTLUhQICAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABFjcHJ0AAABUAAAADNkZXNjAAABhAAAAGx3dHB0AAAB8AAAABRia3B0AAACBAAAABRyWFlaAAACGAAAABRnWFlaAAACLAAAABRiWFlaAAACQAAAABRkbW5kAAACVAAAAHBkbWRkAAACxAAAAIh2dWVkAAADTAAAAIZ2aWV3AAAD1AAAACRsdW1pAAAD+AAAABRtZWFzAAAEDAAAACR0ZWNoAAAEMAAAAAxyVFJDAAAEPAAACAxnVFJDAAAEPAAACAxiVFJDAAAEPAAACAx0ZXh0AAAAAENvcHlyaWdodCAoYykgMTk5OCBIZXdsZXR0LVBhY2thcmQgQ29tcGFueQAAZGVzYwAAAAAAAAASc1JHQiBJRUM2MTk2Ni0yLjEAAAAAAAAAAAAAABJzUkdCIElFQzYxOTY2LTIuMQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAWFlaIAAAAAAAAPNRAAEAAAABFsxYWVogAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAFhZWiAAAAAAAABvogAAOPUAAAOQWFlaIAAAAAAAAGKZAAC3hQAAGNpYWVogAAAAAAAAJKAAAA+EAAC2z2Rlc2MAAAAAAAAAFklFQyBodHRwOi8vd3d3LmllYy5jaAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAFklFQyBodHRwOi8vd3d3LmllYy5jaAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABkZXNjAAAAAAAAAC5JRUMgNjE5NjYtMi4xIERlZmF1bHQgUkdCIGNvbG91ciBzcGFjZSAtIHNSR0IAAAAAAAAAAAAAAC5JRUMgNjE5NjYtMi4xIERlZmF1bHQgUkdCIGNvbG91ciBzcGFjZSAtIHNSR0IAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAZGVzYwAAAAAAAAAsUmVmZXJlbmNlIFZpZXdpbmcgQ29uZGl0aW9uIGluIElFQzYxOTY2LTIuMQAAAAAAAAAAAAAALFJlZmVyZW5jZSBWaWV3aW5nIENvbmRpdGlvbiBpbiBJRUM2MTk2Ni0yLjEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAHZpZXcAAAAAABOk/gAUXy4AEM8UAAPtzAAEEwsAA1yeAAAAAVhZWiAAAAAAAEwJVgBQAAAAVx/nbWVhcwAAAAAAAAABAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAo8AAAACc2lnIAAAAABDUlQgY3VydgAAAAAAAAQAAAAABQAKAA8AFAAZAB4AIwAoAC0AMgA3ADsAQABFAEoATwBUAFkAXgBjAGgAbQByAHcAfACBAIYAiwCQAJUAmgCfAKQAqQCuALIAtwC8AMEAxgDLANAA1QDbAOAA5QDrAPAA9gD7AQEBBwENARMBGQEfASUBKwEyATgBPgFFAUwBUgFZAWABZwFuAXUBfAGDAYsBkgGaAaEBqQGxAbkBwQHJAdEB2QHhAekB8gH6AgMCDAIUAh0CJgIvAjgCQQJLAlQCXQJnAnECegKEAo4CmAKiAqwCtgLBAssC1QLgAusC9QMAAwsDFgMhAy0DOANDA08DWgNmA3IDfgOKA5YDogOuA7oDxwPTA+AD7AP5BAYEEwQgBC0EOwRIBFUEYwRxBH4EjASaBKgEtgTEBNME4QTwBP4FDQUcBSsFOgVJBVgFZwV3BYYFlgWmBbUFxQXVBeUF9gYGBhYGJwY3BkgGWQZqBnsGjAadBq8GwAbRBuMG9QcHBxkHKwc9B08HYQd0B4YHmQesB78H0gflB/gICwgfCDIIRghaCG4IggiWCKoIvgjSCOcI+wkQCSUJOglPCWQJeQmPCaQJugnPCeUJ+woRCicKPQpUCmoKgQqYCq4KxQrcCvMLCwsiCzkLUQtpC4ALmAuwC8gL4Qv5DBIMKgxDDFwMdQyODKcMwAzZDPMNDQ0mDUANWg10DY4NqQ3DDd4N+A4TDi4OSQ5kDn8Omw62DtIO7g8JDyUPQQ9eD3oPlg+zD88P7BAJECYQQxBhEH4QmxC5ENcQ9RETETERTxFtEYwRqhHJEegSBxImEkUSZBKEEqMSwxLjEwMTIxNDE2MTgxOkE8UT5RQGFCcUSRRqFIsUrRTOFPAVEhU0FVYVeBWbFb0V4BYDFiYWSRZsFo8WshbWFvoXHRdBF2UXiReuF9IX9xgbGEAYZRiKGK8Y1Rj6GSAZRRlrGZEZtxndGgQaKhpRGncanhrFGuwbFBs7G2MbihuyG9ocAhwqHFIcexyjHMwc9R0eHUcdcB2ZHcMd7B4WHkAeah6UHr4e6R8THz4faR+UH78f6iAVIEEgbCCYIMQg8CEcIUghdSGhIc4h+yInIlUigiKvIt0jCiM4I2YjlCPCI/AkHyRNJHwkqyTaJQklOCVoJZclxyX3JicmVyaHJrcm6CcYJ0kneierJ9woDSg/KHEooijUKQYpOClrKZ0p0CoCKjUqaCqbKs8rAis2K2krnSvRLAUsOSxuLKIs1y0MLUEtdi2rLeEuFi5MLoIuty7uLyQvWi+RL8cv/jA1MGwwpDDbMRIxSjGCMbox8jIqMmMymzLUMw0zRjN/M7gz8TQrNGU0njTYNRM1TTWHNcI1/TY3NnI2rjbpNyQ3YDecN9c4FDhQOIw4yDkFOUI5fzm8Ofk6Njp0OrI67zstO2s7qjvoPCc8ZTykPOM9Ij1hPaE94D4gPmA+oD7gPyE/YT+iP+JAI0BkQKZA50EpQWpBrEHuQjBCckK1QvdDOkN9Q8BEA0RHRIpEzkUSRVVFmkXeRiJGZ0arRvBHNUd7R8BIBUhLSJFI10kdSWNJqUnwSjdKfUrESwxLU0uaS+JMKkxyTLpNAk1KTZNN3E4lTm5Ot08AT0lPk0/dUCdQcVC7UQZRUFGbUeZSMVJ8UsdTE1NfU6pT9lRCVI9U21UoVXVVwlYPVlxWqVb3V0RXklfgWC9YfVjLWRpZaVm4WgdaVlqmWvVbRVuVW+VcNVyGXNZdJ114XcleGl5sXr1fD19hX7NgBWBXYKpg/GFPYaJh9WJJYpxi8GNDY5dj62RAZJRk6WU9ZZJl52Y9ZpJm6Gc9Z5Nn6Wg/aJZo7GlDaZpp8WpIap9q92tPa6dr/2xXbK9tCG1gbbluEm5rbsRvHm94b9FwK3CGcOBxOnGVcfByS3KmcwFzXXO4dBR0cHTMdSh1hXXhdj52m3b4d1Z3s3gReG54zHkqeYl553pGeqV7BHtje8J8IXyBfOF9QX2hfgF+Yn7CfyN/hH/lgEeAqIEKgWuBzYIwgpKC9INXg7qEHYSAhOOFR4Wrhg6GcobXhzuHn4gEiGmIzokziZmJ/opkisqLMIuWi/yMY4zKjTGNmI3/jmaOzo82j56QBpBukNaRP5GokhGSepLjk02TtpQglIqU9JVflcmWNJaflwqXdZfgmEyYuJkkmZCZ/JpomtWbQpuvnByciZz3nWSd0p5Anq6fHZ+Ln/qgaaDYoUehtqImopajBqN2o+akVqTHpTilqaYapoum/adup+CoUqjEqTepqaocqo+rAqt1q+msXKzQrUStuK4trqGvFq+LsACwdbDqsWCx1rJLssKzOLOutCW0nLUTtYq2AbZ5tvC3aLfguFm40blKucK6O7q1uy67p7whvJu9Fb2Pvgq+hL7/v3q/9cBwwOzBZ8Hjwl/C28NYw9TEUcTOxUvFyMZGxsPHQce/yD3IvMk6ybnKOMq3yzbLtsw1zLXNNc21zjbOts83z7jQOdC60TzRvtI/0sHTRNPG1EnUy9VO1dHWVdbY11zX4Nhk2OjZbNnx2nba+9uA3AXcit0Q3ZbeHN6i3ynfr+A24L3hROHM4lPi2+Nj4+vkc+T85YTmDeaW5x/nqegy6LzpRunQ6lvq5etw6/vshu0R7ZzuKO6070DvzPBY8OXxcvH/8ozzGfOn9DT0wvVQ9d72bfb794r4Gfio+Tj5x/pX+uf7d/wH/Jj9Kf26/kv+3P9t////2wBDAAMCAgICAgMCAgIDAwMDBAYEBAQEBAgGBgUGCQgKCgkICQkKDA8MCgsOCwkJDRENDg8QEBEQCgwSExIQEw8QEBD/2wBDAQMDAwQDBAgEBAgQCwkLEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBD/wAARCABBAEYDAREAAhEBAxEB/8QAHAAAAgMBAQEBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAgGBwkFAQMC/8QALxAAAQMDBAECBQQCAwAAAAAAAQIDBAUGEQAHEiEIEzEJFCJBUSMyQoEkYUNicf/EABsBAQACAwEBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABAgMEBgUH/8QAMhEAAQMCBQMBBwIHAAAAAAAAAQACEQMEBQYSITFBUWFxBxMUIjKBkcHRI4KhseHw8f/aAAwDAQACEQMRAD8A1T0RGiI0RGiI0RGiI0RGiI0RKr8Q/fu6dkdnYrm2d8R6JelSqbCYkdMduRJkwwFB8toWlSUBJLZLigBgFIOSBohUD8G/Ppjc+gLtHyDuyh0m72pTMemyXUJiCqIcSRhWP0g6FjH0lIUFJwM50UAp3nKhCacDLklsOE8Qjl9SjjOAPcnAzgd6KVCt7txjtns1d248AtuP0WjyJcUOJJQZAThoKHvj1CnI6+/toizq2n+JtvFb1aSxuiilXTS+ZD/pttRpgSPctKbCUZHvxWkj7ch76mFUFMdsH5y3Xvpc1YodO25pkKHAa9cTxUVuCOkrwhC0cB6iyM9JUnsfjXGZ2zjbZMw/4yvuTsB39O56D8kgArPb0Kt3VFGkNz+AO5/3dMjB3IpyajBpNaUzGfqbyY8RTauSXHSgqCD+DhJ/vrXH5B9qL813j7C9otY4Brg5j9bTqEhp6hwEz5BBgrfxKwp2DWuDvqMQRBkfopkCCMg519iXlr3REku/ngLUt594K1uTXbsqdTiVRTQYp6ZiI7cZhttKEsg8SrjkFWAR2onPesTjUHAVgGnlVZfXgPtouiqs6CRYdxRHCuPUEocmQ5jak9tyU8uZ7+pLiDlJJBCgcDG2sWuh6saYIlqsqTXdk7VVsrevkdcsyj3jafqUeiFUuQYkqUB6ZdcSErzyCWlhalJP1pSokZGrseDwqlpHKhPk/wCT1xWrcN/7O3+8iq2hfwZXQZcdICaRCQhtuTHeAQFOlTgWpRSpSkApPfIJTJJeCWFQdjuo5tRK8K9v4LtInbzWtT6g2yUvy4tLlzkvKUj6kmYtnDgwcFKSB2Rj31UsqP8AqKgQOFccyy4m27tHr2270Z6jVmmM1CI7EgpjNyWHBzQsN4T3hXsrBwR+Ma+ae0TJr8029NjHDWwyJ4K9HDb1tjVL3CQRB7qKX2jc7cZpw028DZj9EbcqNMqPpKC36gnBaaHpkllCsEFz7Z/aRnXkezzIpyzUdXugNbjqMcTBAiO0k9BwBwoxW7biFZhpg6WAxPJJ/ZVztN8RPdXZ6XcFs75wKxd82MltEKI/6EZ6M9yPqF18JypspKeJCVfkdHX2hp1CQvP4TDeMHnvWfI69qrasTaL5ZimUxVQXJg1Uyik+s22hC0lpITy5LIOc/pnrUqJTiaKVzK3b9MrkV1mbCYdcUgpQtaAVJOOiDqj2B4VmuLSqLmbT1moT0QKjbLE5LDoWy5IaS422oezieQISoD+Q71o+7fMQs+pp3UI8hPGDbGZQIN27uLiC17NjyahImqLwEFCykvJ9No83wtSUHh3yUB99bDWVGbArES13KTa6/GqwLsqS6tsdfNOTHqaw3EYiuGZS3lKPFsBSMuxSo4BbcScH2A9tW965uzwqaQeFqZZ1iUhe2VtWdcT8OuO0Klxaa/KaKSlT7DSW3CkpAx9ST10fz3rI+m2oPmQGF3abYtpUqA9TIdCiiPI6dStHPn/6TqraLGiAEkpNvOHwPpF+W0rcjaSkzBdVHbxJpsd5SlVOICTwbB/5W8koH8gSn346s1oYNlB3Uj+Hj4n3z47Ua5Lm3EdZj1a6kRGmqW08HVRGGS4rLy0jiXVKdPSSQkDsknq6gCFVu5fxPahYnkFVaZQaEK7t5AUKW+1ISmNJ+aZWpLz7C8ZCVK6CXcg8M/RnUKU9O2W6Vkbu2lAvOxa2xUIE9ht/ilafVjlQz6byASW1pOQUn7g+470lF1W7wtd2Y7T2a9CckMHi6hDoV6Z/CsdJ/vXL1864BbXAtq901pJgEyGk9tZGif5lsts67m6mtP6/jlUL8RCiXHXvEe902yguuwGo1UktAn9SLGfQ86OvwlHL7j6e9dPPBC1isr/GnY3f/c6ZNu6wHZ1rwKU0tEmusB1PSkkFsFsguZBwcHABJP41L3ho7qrQXFMrsE7vJsIxce21QvFhiBUpTEmI3GfW2JKQk8nmXB9TKlftWjGTwyeuzwmbcZr24bQtnFoIlzhEjeAO8eR6L6HkzAqF4H3Ny0OIMNaZjiSexPg+qaHYvfmqv7iQbBrVclTWaoHG0Mzlc3WXEtqcSttw9rbIQpJ7IBx7Ho6OVMXvX3Qt6z9dN0weYI9dx6H7LfzbgllSszdUWCnUbEgbSDt02PqPumRu69rQsGhv3Le1y02h0qOMuS6hJQw0DjIHJRGScdAZJ+w19KXy9c3brdjbfdqkrrm216Uq4YTJQl5cJ8LLKlp5JS4npTaik54qAP8ArREnW8fw4bDuS6Zl2xX6/FFRlOS5rECWn0nVrUVLwFpUWskn9p6z1jWAuezZXhrlWNleGFU2S3ahbjRNxZb9t0Wosy4lL+SeanPhR48JDyFBsoaUsEnBC0o7SnJGuXztWrDL14aB0uDCZ8D6gPJbI+627CmDcsDtxP8Az+qqzdOFt5tHvQq3tu591QqvMjN1V2azUUvSWX8OyC02ooC0hwISnlyWRyOUkDB6jIGP3eeMo07nHKNLQ/Wws0/wywHQJa4kd9uO0LysUs24bfOZQcZEGZ3nlXNsr8TG3qJbDm1/kVZtdkvIVLjz6g0EOq9GQ4taI7sVYQsJQ24lsYKiUpHWth1KzpAUsPj3LQGt08QBG3jZZWmpE1fq6yrc24+I94Z06FEsqjxK3Z1Ki/4rTcmhcYrLYGAVFhTmEkf6yPvjVQ0AQrSvpvBtpbF/VaNVbMnZg1GI1OpdQhH1GZEd1PNJSR+5PeUkHIyca5vFcIp3zgZhw4PjsR1C6fA8eq4W0tjU08jjccEHoVUG5viVdFa2yuJQlVyfcCYoXQltuiNHRJStKi26SDlDiQUnJHfE561XB8FpYW/3nJPiP3WTHsyVsYYKUQ0eZP8AYf5Sk3xtB5rXwLdoVz2Hf1xNU2OYNJZb/wA8QmkqOUpPMpazkDmr+IHeAAOmDm9FyUFaFfDK8aN0NirRuu5N1Ykyi1S6ZMdpuhvuNOekzHCyiQtTalDmv1lJ4nBAb79xqZlSAnXIBGCMjRSuNctuRK7TXIpYb9T3SriNYa9FtemWOEgq7HljpCXaf4aWNW9xW9yJtAWa4xw9N/5txLQKEFCVemDjISca8Shg/wAPh5wil8tsZGgcQ4yRPMEk7Txtwtl9dr63xDhL+/ouruT4x2vfj8Gs3httatxTKPCVBhvSoCS40wU8QnKSOXEft5ZKT2nB16lKi+3YKdPZoEADYADoFgc5rySeSs1t9vCDczbWvSp9hWtVrktlwFbbcdsuzYX/AEcQBydA/i4kHr3APZ2mVJEO5WIthajeHu00/a/xzse1rtiPGuNQPnZzctxTi4zz6i6WByJ4JbCkoCB0OJxq0A7oNldymWVtllbSCg9FJSMH+tIRfmPGjxGgxGZQ02MkJQMDSIRfTAHtqUXuiI0RGiI0RGiI0RGiI0RGiI0RGiI0RGiI0RGiI0RGiI0Rf//Z"
    }
]
```

}

```
private void parseJSONResponse(JSONObject response) {

    final JsonArray jsonArr = response.getJSONArray("products");;
        //final List<Country> cards
        ArrayList<MyPojo> numberList = new Gson().fromJson(jsonArr,
                new TypeToken<List<MyPojo>>() {
                }.getType());

for(MyPojo model : numberList) {

            afterSelectionItems.add(model); 

      }
}
```

POJO:

```
import java.util.List;

public class MyPojo{
    private List<Products> products;

    public List<Products> getProducts(){
        return this.products;
    }
    public void setProducts(List<Products> products){
        this.products = products;
    }
}


    import java.util.List;

    public class Products{
        private String entity_id;
        private String name;
        private String price;
        private String short_description;
        private String thumbnail;

        public String getEntity_id(){
            return this.entity_id;
        }
        public void setEntity_id(String entity_id){
            this.entity_id = entity_id;
        }
        public String getName(){
            return this.name;
        }
        public void setName(String name){
            this.name = name;
        }
        public String getPrice(){
            return this.price;
        }
        public void setPrice(String price){
            this.price = price;
        }
        public String getShort_description(){
            return this.short_description;
        }
        public void setShort_description(String short_description){
            this.short_description = short_description;
        }
        public String getThumbnail(){
            return this.thumbnail;
        }
        public void setThumbnail(String thumbnail){
            this.thumbnail = thumbnail;
        }
    }
```

if you are lazy like me use pojo generator for your json response http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

if you failed display full json response in logCat try this [Android Volley Library doen't return whole response data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18738855/android-volley-library-doent-return-whole-response-data/18757287#18757287)

Answer (score 2):

Volley has helpful error classes that can help you with error handling. Example:

```
public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {                
    if(error instanceof NoConnectionError)
        Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, "No internet available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    else if(error instanceof ServerError)
        Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, "Invalid username/password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();    
    }
}
```

Have a look at the error classes available: https://github.com/mcxiaoke/android-volley/tree/master/src/com/android/volley

Hope it helps

Comment: link is broken. I think its this: https://github.com/mcxiaoke/android-volley/tree/master/src/main/java/com/android/volley