# Android Volley Library doen't return whole response data

Tags: android, httpconnection, android-volley, androidhttpclient

Volley library doesn't return whole response data. It only return the part of the response data. I am calling drupal services. Below is my code for it.

```
public void BoardRoomRequest() {
        pdialog = new ProgressDialog(BoardRoom.this);
        pdialog.setTitle("Please wait....");
        String url = Global_Application.url + "views/boardroom";
        Log.d("url========", url);
        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
        StringRequest req = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET,
                getApplicationContext(), url, params,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        Log.d("Response", response);

                        pdialog.dismiss();
                    }
                }, new ErrorListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        Log.d("Error.Response", error.toString());
                        pdialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });

        queue.add(req);
        pdialog.show();
    }
```

Comment: welcome to SO! follow the rules http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask ,  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not the problem with Volley!, it's the problem(limitation) of logcat for displaying limited size of data. (I'm assuming you are reading the response in logcat from your code)

if you are using eclipse here is the solution

```
 public void BoardRoomRequest() {
            pdialog = new ProgressDialog(BoardRoom.this);
            pdialog.setTitle("Please wait....");
            String url = Global_Application.url + "views/boardroom";
            Log.d("url========", url);
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            StringRequest req = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET,
                    getApplicationContext(), url, params,
                    new Response.Listener<String>() {

                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(String response) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                       // Log.d("Response", response);  //can't display more data

                    //=========================
                    longInfo(response); //solution for displaying more data in logcat
                    //=========================

                            pdialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    }, new ErrorListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            Log.d("Error.Response", error.toString());
                            pdialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });

            queue.add(req);
            pdialog.show();
        }   

public void longInfo(String str) {
            if(str.length() > 4000) {
                Log.i("",str.substring(0, 4000));
                longInfo(str.substring(4000));
            } else
                Log.i("",str);
        }
```

**Note:** $ adb logcat -g
ring buffer is 64Kb (63Kb consumed), max entry is 4096b, max payload is 4076b

LogCat is very much device dependent. The size and also the handling of bad character differs between different handsets.

Give it try for this also:

```
     import java.util.*;

        class Test
        {
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(
        "Thequickbrownfoxjumps".split("(?<=\\G.{4})")
        ));
        }
        }

output: [Theq, uick, brow, nfox, jump, s]
```